# Relational Database design: handling sales receipts

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

I am making an online market for a learning project. Pardon me for not having a diagram.

I have the tables `Seller` and `Product`,which contains data about the seller and products, respectively. A Seller can have multiple products. There is also a `Receipt` table that stores information regarding purchases made by a customer. This is an important record and must persist. The receipt should be able to have information on the item purchased.

However, products are dynamic, products may be added and removed. But since the Receipt should reference the Product, it means that I should not delete a Product row even if it is no longer on sale.

Is this the right way to do it? Are there any better design pattern I can use?

Comment: You might want to read about "slowly changing dimensions type 2". Basically, each product record will also have to have a validity date range (from-to). You will never delete a product record, but you will have to update the end date whenever a product is discontinued.

Comment: It is common to add a "Deleted" or "Active" or "Inactive" to the product table.

Comment: Thanks! They are really helpful. I will look into them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the right way to do it. If you set the referential integrity right, the system will not allow you to delete a product or seller if it has receipts. The next thing to do is to use a flag to mark the product or seller as deleted or archived. It could be either a boolean or a date that indicates when it became inactive. Using a 'From' AND a 'To' date to indicate valid time intervals, as Hellmar Becker suggests, is very powerfull, but it opens a whole new can of worms: you can have more than one 'valid' period, so you have to extend your primary key. 
Modern databases like HANA (from SAP) just don't allow deletes any more, and have inbuilt 'deleted' flags.

Comment: I read about what he suggested, and it sure is powerful. What do you mean by "extend your primary key"? I do understand that the product period may be "renewed"

Comment: Normally, a ProductId would be the unique key, but if you add a 'from' and 'to' date, you can have many records with the same ProductId, signifying multiple valid periods. ProductId is not unique any more, and not sufficient for a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a proper answer. I just want to give you the gift of a diagram since you didn't have one! :)
[image: QuickDatabaseDiagram]

(Disclaimer: [QuickDatabaseDiagrams](https://www.quickdatabasediagrams.com) is my project)